# How do I tell my service (all calls REST/JSON) to handle OPTIONS requests?

Tags: asp.net, iis, cors

I have written a WCF service to return JSON on REST requests. Works great with a browser hitting it. But when my JavaScript hits it, the first request is an OPTIONS request for the url with "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET".

I think I need to handle CORS [as documented here](http://enable-cors.org/server_wcf.html). However the suggested code won't compile and the suggested web.config is illegal in places.

What do I need to do so the service will respond appropriately when asked if a GET can be requested on a url?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to enable it in IIS as well: http://encosia.com/using-cors-to-access-asp-net-services-across-domains/

Comment: Unfortunately I'm doing WCF, not ASP.NET and for WCF there's a lot more required (no idea why). Thanks - dave